# Error 'unknown MongoDB operation 'aggregate'' when using aggregate in WSo2 Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am working Wso2 Integration Studio 8.1 version. I want to using aggregate query. But Wso2 Integration Studip giving error as `DS Fault Message: Error in MongoQuery.runQuery: DS Fault Message: Unknown MongoDB operation 'aggregate'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it seems the Micro Integrator doesn't support it at the moment. This is from the [code](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/a0333bc9ad8d9c76f6eb0be14cd6984d8051ad72/components/data/data-services/org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/micro/integrator/dataservices/core/description/query/MongoQuery.java#L281) which supports the following operations.

```java
private DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation convertToMongoOp(String operation) throws DataServiceFault {
        if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.COUNT.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.COUNT;
        } else if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.DROP.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.DROP;
        } else if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.FIND.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.FIND;
        } else if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.FIND_ONE.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.FIND_ONE;
        } else if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.INSERT.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.INSERT;
        } else if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.REMOVE.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.REMOVE;
        } else if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.UPDATE.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.UPDATE;
        } else if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.EXISTS.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.EXISTS;
        }  else if (DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperationLabels.CREATE.equals(operation)) {
            return DBConstants.MongoDB.MongoOperation.CREATE;
        } else {
            throw new DataServiceFault("Unknown MongoDB operation '" + operation + "'");
        }
    }
```

Even the [MongoDB connector](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/mongodb-connector/mongodb-connector-config/) doesn't support Aggregate operation, hence your best option is to write a Custom mediator to get this done or try to improve the existing connector.

Comment: Thank you for answered. So ı have a data service project in wso2 integration studio. How ı add custom mediator in data service project? Can u give a example custom meadiator that mongo db aggregate operation

Comment: @AhmetKalem You can't add custom mediators to Data services. What you can do is, create an API/Proxy and use a class mediator to get the aggregated data in the integration layer. You can refer to this document to learn about class mediators https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/class-Mediator/